# 2 selectors, 2 different events, same function

Tags: jquery

I'm using jQuery 1.7 and need to bind the same function to 2 different live events on 2 different selectors, like:

```
function do_something(_this){
  // do something with _this
  alert("test");
}

$("input").live("keyup", function({
  do_something($(this));
});

$("select").live("change", function({
  do_something($(this));
});
```

This works, but I would really like if I could somehow pull all this into one statement, like:

```
// pseudo code
( $("input").live("keyup") || $("select").live("change") ).bind(function(){
  // do something with $(this)
  alert("test");
});
```

Is that possible?

Comment: don't you think the former version is far more readable than the second ?

Comment: True, but if I had the elegant solution myself, I wouldn't ask here :) Consider my pseudo code just an example, for something a little hard to explain.

Comment: Just edited my question, because I actually need to do something with $(this) in the function, and that's why I would prefer a single selector. Something that might not have been entirely clear in my first edit...

Comment: @jetsie Have a look at the upvoted answers. In these answers, replace `do_something` with `func`, and create a function `var func = function(ev){do_something($(this));}`. That's the closest you can get, without making the code unreadable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the `do_something()` function into the `.live()` function directly and avoid the anonymous function. That saves a few characters.

```js
$("input").live("keyup", do_something );
$("select").live("change", do_something );
```

To convert to the jQuery 1.7 syntax, you need to use a delegate (which `.live()` did for you). You can use the `<form>` where your input and select elements are or the `document`.

```js
$( document ).on( "keyup", "input", do_something );
$( document ).on( "change", "select", do_something );
```

And if you really want to put both events and selectors in one call, you can. Since you're going to the same function anyway, and since you're using a delegate there are only two events total. If you really think you need it, you can check the event in the callback to make sure the right one matches the selector (as I show in the demo).

```js
$( document ).on( "keyup change", "input, select", do_something );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/6ZUMa/

HTML:

```html
<input />
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Script:

```js
$( document ).on( 'keyup change', 'input, select', do_something );

function do_something( event ) {

    //this if() statement probably isn't needed for your purposes
    if( ( event.type == 'keyup' && event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input' )
      || ( event.type == 'change' && event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'select' ) ) {

        //process event here
        $( 'input' ).val( event.type );

    };

};
```

Comment: Yep. Also, it's better to use `on` instead of `live` (OP mentioned jQuery 1.7).

Comment: True, it removes some clutter. Still it doesn't quite get me where I wanted, though, but thanks for the idea.

Comment: Thanks for updating, I'm accepting this answer. I have modified my own code, and now using on(), and implemented the pointers given here for simplifying the code a bit, and it works flawlessly. And thanks to Rob W too, for pointing out, that my wish for one statement was... not really necessary, with these pointers in mind.

Comment: `input` DOES throw a `change` event.

Comment: @bazmegakapa It didn't in my demo, but I guess it makes sense it would. Same advice applies in this case though, I dont' think it will affect what he's doing. Thanks, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input').on('keyup', do_something);
$('select').on('change', do_something);
```

Note that as of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers instead. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

If you need `live()`-like functionality, use:

```
$(document).on('keyup change', 'input, select', do_something);
```

Comment: +1 for also mentioning that `live()` is deprecated. It will be hard to make people stop using it, even though it was *not recommended* for quite a long time.

Comment: This format of `.on()` isn't equivalent to `.live()`, it's equivalent to `.bind()`.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff Right. Edited my answer with a clarification, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".my_selector").live("keyup change", function({
  do_something();
```

});

This should work if you add class my_selectror to your elements.

Comment: This binds two events to the same selector, omitting the other one. Each selector has to get only one event.

Answer (score -1):

Please note that the .live method is severely deprecated.
http://api.jquery.com/live/

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().

With the .on() method, you can do things like:

```
$("input, select").on("focusout", function(){
    alert( "focus lost on " + $(this).attr("id") );
});
```

With the focus out event, you can do something when any input field or select item loses focus (i.e. the user has moved on to another item that is now in focus).

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: 1. The poster is using a deprecated method. I think it's imoportant that I make a note of this and suggest using a method that basically does the same, but is not deprecated?
2. Binding 2 different object to 2 different events can't really be done in one statement. How does jQuery know to bind both events to both items, or bind one event to one item? You can't do that with a single selection. However, "focusout" is a valid event that works in both cases. Then you only have 1 event, thus you are able to bind the function to the same event.

Comment: @Flater `change` would work fine, but I guess he wants to use `keyup` for a reason.

Comment: What the OP requested is not possible, so I get downvoted for suggesting an alternative.