# How to use 'or' condition in method of jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Assume that I have following code.

Code 01

```
$("#abc").click(function(){
    //My Code
});
```

Code 02

```
$("#def").change(function(){
    //My Code
});
```

I have to run same code `#abc` click or `#def` change. So currently I have wasting time writing same code in two places.

**I know that it is possible to reuse same code, creating a common function and calling it.**

Is there any jQuery way to solve my question.

I mean something like following.

```
(`#abc` click or `#def` change){
 //Do this
}
```

Comment: You don't need to write same code twice. Use function in that case. You can follow the answer of @Milind  Wrap everything in a function and use that. This is the best solution. Good luck.

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/8892468/1581226

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is

```
var todo = function() {
   //something
}

$('#abc').click(todo);
$('#def').change(todo);
```

This ofcourse you already cameup with (*I know that it is possible to reuse same code, creating a common function and calling it.*)

Comment: Actually, I was one person who downvotes this answer because I expected there is an answer......

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-define a function and use it as parameter while setting function to different events. Something like this:

```
 var someEvent = function() {
   // code here
 });


 $('#abc').on('click', someEvent);
 $('#def').on('change', someEvent);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Call the same function from event handlers

```js
$("#abc").change(samefunction);
$("#def").click(samefunction);



function samefunction(e) {
  alert(e.target.id)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="abc" />
<input type="button" id="def" value="click" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't register 2 different **events** with the same jQuery selector for 2 different **selections**. That's when functions come in handy:

```
function go() {
}

$('#abc').click(go);
$('#def').change(go);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can only do this if your event registrations are common to your selectors. YOu can do something like below:

```
$("#abc  , #def ").on("click change", functionname);
```

Comment: This leads to trigger events that are unwanted.

Comment: What do you mean by "event registrations are common to your selectors"?

Comment: @questioner  - if click and change are common to abc and def selectors

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - this can be suitable for common event handlers

Comment: This will produce unintended results. What happens if someone clicks on `#def` or changes `#abc`?

Comment: @e_i_pi - this is only suitable for valid and tested use case. Period.

Comment: Solution I have given is kind of OR use case and works!